# Specifying the destination for the pdf output when using pdflatex, from gVim

Tags: windows, pdf, vim, latex, pdflatex

I am generating a pdf output with `pdflatex` with the following command in gVim:

```
:!pdflatex %
```

This command in turns executes the following in the Command Prompt:

```
cmd.exe /c pdflatex /testvim.tex
```

---

Now, the problem I'm having with this is that the pdf is outputted to the `system32` folder:

```
C:\windows\system32\testvim.pdf
```

**How can I instruct `pdflatex` to generate the pdf in the folder where the `tex` file resides?**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can use

```
-output-directory <wherever>
```

To get the directory of the current file, you'll need to use:

```
expand('%:h')
```

but you'll need to write a macro or a function that can evaluate that; something like:

```
map ,,p :exe "!pdflatex -output-directory " . expand('%:h') . " %"<CR>
```